# what's the best way to store private large data on android?

Tags: android, file, save

- I write a android game that load level data from file.
- level data contain some image and text file.
- user can download new package (contain some level).
- My problem is how to save level file that user can't see or edit it.

1 ) use internal storage (Current):

- on some device internal storage has low space.
- on rooted device user can see or edit level file.

2 ) use password protected zip contains package file.

- can I read/edit some file from it without extract all file?
- I can save this on external storage.
- where keep package password ?

3 ) your idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Also, take a look at the solution given here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49921/how-do-i-store-level-data-in-android

Comment: Have you considered a private content provider, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported

Comment: Thanks for all comments. and about @alvaro.delaserna comment , I can't use Internal storage for reasons before tell in question. may be use password protected zip and extract each level temporary and delete it after level is loaded.